# Why specify certain vector space sums as direct?

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

I know that

> The sum [of vector spaces] $U_1+\cdots+U_m$ is *direct* if every $v\in U_1+\cdots+U_m$ has a unique expression as $v=u_1+\cdots+u_m$ for $u_1\in U_1,\ldots,u_m\in U_m$.

I also recognise that

> A basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is defined if every $v\in V$ has a unique expression as $v=a^1 e_1+\cdots+a^n e_n$ for $e_1,\ldots,e_n\in V$.

These parallels are blatantly obvious. Obviously understanding the basis for a vector spaces is fundamentally important. However direct sums are given an equal amount of significance it seems.

Why are these sums of vector spaces specifically defined as direct? What makes them so special?

Comment: A vector space being a direct sum of subspaces is something we noticed happening over and over again, and it was useful to note, so we gave the phenomenon a name.

Comment: @runway44 Nicely stated. Care to expound?

Comment: For example, rotations matrices $R$ satisfy $R^TR=I$ and $\det R=1$. In 3D, a rotation is around an axis. That means $\Bbb R^3$ is a direct sum of a fixed line (the axis) and a plane (the plane of rotation). What happens in higher dimensions? Turns out, for every rotation $R$, the space $\Bbb R^n$ is a direct sum of orthogonal 2D subspaces (and possibly a 1D subspace if $n$ is odd, like $n=3$) and $R$ rotates each of the planes independently.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, the basis definition is a special case. 
If $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a $K$-basis of a vector space $V$, then the sum
$V=Ke_1+\ldots+Ke_n$ is direct, where $Ke_i =\{ke_i\mid k\in K\}$ is a 1-dimensional subspace of $V$.

Again: Those two definitions are different. The definition of basis leads directly to the above direct sum of 1-dim. vector spaces.
But not each direct sum of vector spaces consists of 1-dim. spaces.

Comment: I’m asking about the direct sums of vector spaces, not the sums of vectors within those spaces.

Comment: I don't see any evidence indicating Wuestenfux doesn't understand that.